# My recycleview isn't working. Can you help me?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I really need some help. I'm new in android studio. I'm having a problem about my recyclerview, it wont show some items but there's no errors.

**Adapter:**

```
public class ClassAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClassAdapter.ClassViewHolder> {
       private ArrayList<ExampleClass> qClassList;

       public static class ClassViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       public TextView code,name,year;
       public ClassViewHolder(View view){
              super(view);
              code = view.findViewById(R.id.code);
              name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
              year = view.findViewById(R.id.year);

              }
       }
       public ClassAdapter(ArrayList<ExampleClass> classList){
       qClassList = classList;

       }

       @NonNull
       @Override
       public ClassViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
              View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_classes, viewGroup, false);
              ClassViewHolder cvh = new ClassViewHolder(v);
              return cvh;
       }

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(ClassViewHolder classViewHolder, int i) 
       {
               ExampleClass exampleClass = qClassList.get(i);
               classViewHolder.code.setText(exampleClass.getqCode());
               classViewHolder.name.setText(exampleClass.getqName());
               classViewHolder.year.setText(exampleClass.getqYear());
               }

               @Override
               public int getItemCount() {
               return qClassList.size();
               }
        }
}
```

**ClassActivity:**

```
     public class ClassActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     private ArrayList<ExampleClass> exampleClassArrayList;

     private RecyclerView recyclerView;
     private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
     private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_classes);
         ArrayList<ExampleClass> exampleClasses = new ArrayList<>();

         exampleClasses.add(new ExampleClass("CANS103","PROGRAMMING 1","BSIT-3"));

         createClassList();
         buildRecycleView();

         FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
         fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 // Click action
                 Intent intent = new Intent(ClassActivity.this, CreateClassActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
             }
         });
     }


     public void createClassList(){
         exampleClassArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

     }

     public void buildRecycleView(){
         recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
         layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
         adapter = new ClassAdapter(exampleClassArrayList);
         recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
         recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**activity_class.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
         android:padding="4dp"
         android:scrollbars="vertical"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

     <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
         android:id="@+id/fab"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/recyclerView"
         android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
         android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
         android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

I've already search some problems similar to mine but it didn't work. I was wondering if someone can tell me whats the mistake I've done here. I would really appreciate it. Sorry for the inconvience.

Comment: Where is your getItemCount() method of RecyclerAdapter. Override it and return the list size.

Comment: Your list `exampleClassArrayList` is empty, so nothing to display ?

Comment: Why are you having two arraylist `exampleClasses` and `exampleClassArrayList`? One is empty and one is not! Just as @Johann67 pointed out `exampleClassArrayList` was instantiated but never given any value.

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi I have it in the end of the adapter.
@Johann67 I put the `exampleClasses.add(new ExampleClass("CANS103","PROGRAMMING 1","BSIT-3"));` for example. It's not appearing when I run it

Comment: `exampleClasses` is not used. You need to populate `exampleClassArrayList` for your exemple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chaneg this Lines of code:

```
 ArrayList<ExampleClass> exampleClasses = new ArrayList<>(); // remove this line No need
          createClassList(); //call this method
         exampleClassArrayList.add(new ExampleClass("CANS103","PROGRAMMING 1","BSIT-3"));
```

After this call

```
buildRecycleView()
```

You are adding in different list (exampleClasses ) and using different list for adapter (exampleClassArrayList) .

Comment: Do i arrange it like this:

`buildRecycleView();
 createClassList();
 exampleClassArrayList.add(new ExampleClass("CANS103","PROGRAMMING 1","BSIT-3"));`

I'm sorry i'm a little confused.

Comment: first call createClassList(), then add exampleClassArrayList.add(new ExampleClass("CANS103","PROGRAMMING 1","BSIT-3")); and last buildRecycleView().

Answer (score 0):

In createClassList() method create a new instance from your list, while you added a new item in onCreate list, remove call createClassList() worked correctly